# Why are no inputs showing up in SSIS multicast transformation?

Tags: ssis, multicast

In my SSIS data flow I have this setup:

[image]

I am trying to split the info into four destinations, two to each multicast. I originally had conditional splits instead of mulitcasts. The input went into the conditional splits just fine, but I was unable to figure out or track down info on how to write a condition that separated purely by column. I am wanting to try out this [method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c582fcd8-8af6-4119-b1c2-799745d9d9c7/how-to-split-list-of-columns-into-2-tables-in-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices). However, when I open either multicast editor, there are no inputs.

Comment: Components in your SSIS data flow either act as Source, Destination or a Transformation. Generally speaking a Source has a regular output path and an error path. Destinations generally accept only one input and only have an error output. Transformations usually are one input path and one output path. Notable exceptions are a Conditional Split and a Multicast. A Multicast allows many consumers to get the same data fed. A Conditional Split allows for filtering of your data (A's on left, B's on the right).

Comment: Based on my cursory reading of the msdn thing, you don't need to worry about only getting columns ABCD to one route and E-Z in another path. In your target table1, you'd only map ABCD in there and table2 is where you'd map E-Z.